# Compare two query result set in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a requirement to compare the row values from yesterday to current day (today). Sample table values below:

table_1

```
   hour                   |   loads
   2022-12-16 00:00:00    |   30000
   2022-12-16 01:00:00    |   40000
```

table_2

```
   hour                   |   loads
   2022-12-15 00:00:00    |   25000
   2022-12-15 01:00:00    |   25000
```

then compare table_1 values to table_2 values. I need to return the difference of each row like

result_table

```
   hour                   |   diff_loads_from_yesterday
   2022-12-16 00:00:00    |   5000
   2022-12-16 01:00:00    |   15000
```

I tried to use UNION ALL but it did not worked. I would appreciate if someone can help me on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [window function](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/#clickhouse-specific-window-functions) i.e. roughly (I've used a diff of 10 places to shorten insert)

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `loads` Int32,
    `time` DateTime
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY time


INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(10, '2022-12-15 00:00:00'), 
(20, '2022-12-15 01:00:00'), 
(30, '2022-12-15 02:00:00'), 
(40, '2022-12-15 03:00:00'), 
(50, '2022-12-15 04:00:00'), 
(60, '2022-12-15 05:00:00'), 
(70, '2022-12-15 06:00:00'), 
(80, '2022-12-15 07:00:00'), 
(90, '2022-12-15 08:00:00'), 
(10, '2022-12-15 09:00:00'), 
(20, '2022-12-15 10:00:00'), 
(30, '2022-12-15 11:00:00'), 
(40, '2022-12-15 12:00:00')

SELECT
    time,
    loads,
    first_value(loads) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS previous,
    loads - previous AS diff
FROM test
ORDER BY time ASC

┌────────────────time─┬─loads─┬─previous─┬─diff─┐
│ 2022-12-15 00:00:00 │    10 │       10 │    0 │
│ 2022-12-15 01:00:00 │    20 │       10 │   10 │
│ 2022-12-15 02:00:00 │    30 │       10 │   20 │
│ 2022-12-15 03:00:00 │    40 │       10 │   30 │
│ 2022-12-15 04:00:00 │    50 │       10 │   40 │
│ 2022-12-15 05:00:00 │    60 │       10 │   50 │
│ 2022-12-15 06:00:00 │    70 │       10 │   60 │
│ 2022-12-15 07:00:00 │    80 │       10 │   70 │
│ 2022-12-15 08:00:00 │    90 │       10 │   80 │
│ 2022-12-15 09:00:00 │    10 │       10 │    0 │
│ 2022-12-15 10:00:00 │    20 │       10 │   10 │
│ 2022-12-15 11:00:00 │    30 │       20 │   10 │
│ 2022-12-15 12:00:00 │    40 │       30 │   10 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

Note first N values are invalid.

Comment: Note: If you need to do this from two distinct different tables, join on the time field and do a date subtraction/addition on the time for one side of the join.